# Don't sort the result set of function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, sorting, auto-generate

I have table in SQL Server called `source` with `source_id` as primary key and `source_name`.

This is my function which is generating an incorrect result.

This is insert statement using below function:

```
insert into ppm_schema.dim_source (source_id, source_name)
values (ppm_schema.generatesourceid('clinical'), 'clinical');

insert into ppm_schema.dim_source (source_id, source_name)
values (ppm_schema.generatesourceid('qivia'), 'qivia');

insert into ppm_schema.dim_source (source_id, source_name)
values (ppm_schema.generatesourceid('ab'), 'ab');

insert into ppm_schema.dim_source (source_id, source_name)
values (ppm_schema.generatesourceid('b'), 'b');
```

```
create function ppm_schema.generatesourceid
    (@SourceName varchar(50))
returns varchar(50)
as
begin
    declare @count varchar(50);
    declare @ide varchar(50);
    declare @maxid varchar(50);
    declare @prefix varchar(20);
    declare @id varchar(20);

    with cte as
    (
        select top 1 
            count(*) + 1 as number
        from 
            ppm_schema.dim_source 
    )
    select @count = number from cte;

    select @prefix = left(@SourceName, 3);

    if len(@SourceName) >= 3
    begin
        select @ide = @prefix + right('000' + cast(@count as varchar(3)), 3)
    end
    else if len(@SourceName) >= 2
    begin
        select @ide = @prefix + 'x'+ right('000' + cast(@count as varchar(3)), 3)
    end
    else if len(@SourceName) >= 1
        select @ide = @prefix + 'xx' + right('000' + cast(@count as varchar(3)), 3)

    return @ide
end
```

Result of this function:

| source_id | source_name |
| --- | --- |
| abx003 | ab |
| bxx004 | b |
| cli001 | clinical |
| qiv002 | qivia |
|  |  |

I need the result to be

| source_id | source_name |
| --- | --- |
| cli001 | clinical |
| qiv001 | qivia |
| abx003 | ab |
| bxx004 | b |

Comment: The order of rows in a SQL query result is arbitrary unless you explicitly define it, e.g. with an ORDER BY.

Comment: If you really need a specific order in your result, you have to define that order. If you don't define  a specific order in your query, the order of the result is per default not specified and the data can come back in any order.

Comment: What makes the first result incorrect and the second one correct? Because the rows are returned in the order they where inserted? If yes, you could add an autoincremented rowid to your table and order the results by that rowid

Comment: Is `dim_source` a dimension table in a data warehouse? All the more reason for it to have a proper primary key instead of "intelligent" keys like `source_id`. Intelligent keys are generally a bad idea but far worse in data warehouses. A tiny change in the "intelligent" rules would force a change of the entire *fact table* instead of the few or even the single dimension row affected. If you want a specific reporting order, add it explicitly through one or more ordering columns, to cover all reporting scenarios

Comment: Your function is not thread safe and will not generate incrementing numerical parts if data is deleted ([this example shows two ending 004](https://dbfiddle.uk/U82R9VNb)). This seems like a fairly arbitrary key, so why not use an identity column, and just create your string ID with a computed column. You can then sort by your integer ID without being influenced by the string part, or having to do any string manipulation. [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/air2k8E7)

Answer (score 1):

**The concerns in the comments are fully valid.**

That said, using an order by in your select statement would put them in the order you list. Because your prefix is always 3 characters, you can pull everything on the right - 3 to use the number (cli**001**) to sort by.

```
select
    *
from ppm_schema.dim_source
order by RIGHT(source_id, LEN(source_id)-3)
```

**Results**

| source_id | source_name |
| --- | --- |
| cli001 | clinical |
| qiv002 | qivia |
| abx003 | ab |
| bxx004 | b |

If that is everything that your function does, you could put it into a single query.

```
create function ppm_schema.generatesourceid
    (@SourceName varchar(50))
returns varchar(50)
as
begin
    return (SELECT 
            LEFT(LEFT(@SourceName, 3) + 'xxx', 3) 
                + RIGHT('000' + CAST(COUNT(*) + 1 AS varchar(3)), 3)
        FROM ppm_schema.dim_source)
end
```

Beyond the scope of the question: The generated ids that I have seen tend to use a sequencer, sequencer table, or at least a lock followed by direct insert.